# Add marker on geojson data layer in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, onclick, polygon, geojson

I have loaded geojson layer to google maps using the following code

```
map.data.loadGeoJson(
  'http://localhost/pssp/assets/geojson/Empanel_Area_2019.geojson');
   map.data.setStyle({
     fillColor: 'red',
     strokeColor: 'red',
     strokeWeight: 1
   });
)
```

When I try to add a marker on the data layer on the click event it will get added outside the data layer but not inside. how can I add a marker in side the polygons in the data layer.

I used the following code to add a marker on click event

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   placeMarker(event.latLng);
});

function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location, 
        map: map
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a click listener to the DataLayer as well.

```
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wobyj51c/)

[image: screenshot of map with markers on polygons]

**code snippet:**

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#info-box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  bottom: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {
        lat: -28,
        lng: 137
      }
    });

    // Load GeoJSON.
    map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');

    // Add some style.
    map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
      return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ ({
        fillColor: feature.getProperty('color'),
        strokeWeight: 1
      });
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      console.log("on map:" + event.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
      placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });

    function placeMarker(location) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
      });
    }
    // Set click event for each feature.
    map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
      console.log("on polygon:" + event.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
      placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```